# Почему код не работает? Выводит мусор и не учитывает пробел, хотя он задан. К тому же мне нужно найти средний размер слов в введенной строке?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define VAL 321
int main(void) {
int z = 0;
char tem[] = { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F',  'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z','a','e','i','o','u','y','b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z' };
char tea[] = { '.',',',' ',';',':','!','-','`','?','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
char* pk, * pn;
char buf[VAL], * p = buf;
printf("\nString: ");
gets_s(buf);
while (*p == ' ') {
    z++;
}
printf("z=%d\n", z);
for (pk = pn = buf; *pk != '\0'; pk++) {
    if (*pk != tea[100])
        *pn++ = *pk;
}
*pn = '\0';
while (*p)
    p++;
printf("Modificated string: %s\n", buf);
printf("Length: %d", strlen(buf));
return 0;
```

}

Comment: изложите, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), что именно «не так» в вашем коде. см. [mcve]

Comment: Что такое "не работает"?

Comment: Выводит мусор, а не значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `gets_s(buf);`

  Стандартная функция `gets_s` [имеет два параметра](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), а не один. Почему вы вызываете ее с одним параметром?
- `if (*pk != tea[100])`

  Что такое `tea[100]`? У вас в массиве `tea` нет элемента с индексом `100`.
- `printf("Length: %d", strlen(buf));`

  Результат функции `strlen` имеет тип `size_t`. Его нельзя печатать через спецификатор формата `%d`.

Comment: 1. Компилятор ругается , если я пишу gets.   2,3 Спасибо , Ошибку понял.

Comment: Какой спецификатор использовать для вывода strlen ?

Comment: @Apobia: Так у вас и сейчас компилятор ругается. И при чем здесь `gets`? Никакого `gets` уже давно нет. Ещё раз: у функции `gets_s` **два** параметра. Вот два и указывайте. А для типа `size_t` правильный формат - `%zu`.

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил все выше сказаное, но после ввода строки и вывода числа z(при чем всегда 0 ,хотя накого не должно быть) более ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Apobia Ваш цикл while проверяет только первый символ. Если этот символ будет пробелом, то цикл будет бесконечно его проверять, а если нет, то цикл ни разу не выполнится и не изменит z. Просто инкрементируйте указатель p, что бы после каждой итерации он указывал на следующий символ в строке.

Comment: Спасибо) Сейчас исправлю)